# Jupyter notebook won't launch after writing "jupyter notebook" in terminal

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, launch

I have been searching this problem since a while, but can't find a solution. I am working in Windows 10.

After I activate any virtual environment and I write "jupyter notebook", the terminal gets stucked and nothing happens, like in the picture:
[image: Nothing happens after I write "Jupyter Notebook"]

No errors appear, I can't Ctrl+C to kill terminal and no browser page appears.

The "jupyter --help" command works, but any other subcommand (like `jupyter lab`, `jupyter nbclassic` or `jupyter run`) doesn't

I tried to do the following, with no results:

- Uninstall and install jupyter again
- I tried to lunch jupyter notebook with Anaconda Navigator
- I tried to open a browser and go to "http://localhost:8889/tree", using different port values
- I tried to restart my laptop

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

If you've re-installed Anaconda with the default settings, it should set up PATH correctly. So I hope the error is not with PATH environment variable

Try the following:

1. If Jupyter gives an error that it can’t find notebook, check with `pip` or `conda` that the `notebook` package is installed.
2. Try running `jupyter-notebook` (with a hyphen). This should normally be the same as `jupyter notebook` (with a space), but if there’s any difference, the version with the hyphen is the ‘real’ launcher, and the other one wraps that.

Comment: Hey @stitchesguy90. Regarding point 1, Jupyter doesn't give any error. I tried option 2, but still nothing happens, same as "jupyter notebook" with a space.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that jupyter notebook was not starting because I could not ping my localhost (127.0.0.1) because of some bad network settings.
After running `netsh winsock reset` in a cmd terminal to reset the network settings, I could ping the localhost and jupyter notebook started to work again.

Comment: I am glad that you could sort it out. I was offline for few days.